# Were Soviet spacecraft production facilities as widely dispersed as American production facilites?

Tags: soviet-union, manufacturing

The geographic location of facilities to produce components of American spacecraft has long been influenced by politics.  High-ranking members of Congress would often pressure NASA officials to award contracts for production in their home state.  The politicians could then boast to their constituents about creating jobs.  As a result, every state has had some role in spacecraft production, even if that means shipping parts great distances, or radically changing the design of components (e.g. segmenting solid rocket boosters to allow for transport).

**Was this also an issue in the Soviet space program?**  Did local politicians try to get facilities in their jurisdiction, and how widely dispersed were actual production facilities?

I would prefer an answer in the Soviet era, if possible; otherwise, a comparison of Roskosmos to NASA would be satisfactory.

Comment: In soviet russia, ***you no get space industry; space industry gets you!*** :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a small measure - yes.

[KOROLEV AND UKRAINE. ROCKET-SPACE PAGES](http://www.cosmoworld.ru/spaceencyclopedia/publications/index.shtml?mitr07.html)

> For the serial production of missiles in the interests of the defense of the USSR, a plant was required: a giant plant. A special state commission, which, at the suggestion of Sergei Korolev, was joined by his deputy, Vasily Budnik, considered suitable options: in the Urals and Ukraine. First we stopped in Kiev. But the people's commissar of weapons Dmitry Ustinov (Ministry of Armaments) protested: "You cannot turn the capital of the Ukrainian republic into a closed city." Then the choice fell on the automobile plant under construction in Dnepropetrovsk. It was converted in 1951 into the serial rocket plant No. 586 (“Yuzhmash”).

In most cases, it was about obtaining orders for the production of components of rockets or satellites by existing plants.

Comment: Did the state commissioners generally avoid placing facilities within their jurisdiction? Or was it generally welcomed?

Comment: @Paul Local authorities always want large investments in their city, region, republic. The decision on large investments was made by the government. Local authorities could lobbying the necessary decision because of their capabilities. Mostly personal connections. For example, personal acquaintances with Sergei Korolev and other key persons allowed the authorities of the city of Evpatoria to push through the construction of a plant for the production of electronic components of satellites.